# Kendo Grid : Default value 1 in cell in inline edit mode, how to change it?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have following config foo column in grid:

**field:**

```
   actionName: {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: true,
                    defaultValue: {"name" : "TEST123"},
                    type: "object"
                  },
```

**Column:**

```
{ 
                field :"actionName",
                title : $translate.instant('ACTIONNAME'),
                width: "200px",
                editor: GlobalHelperService.getActionNamesListForAutocomplete,
                template: '#: data.actionName.name #',
                filterable: { cell: { operator:"contains"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Which works almost fine, but if i clicked on cell item i always got following value (see. image below), instead of the text defined in template attribute.

[image]

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the cleanest way, but you could use the `edit` event like I do in [this blog post](http://blog.falafel.com/kendo-grid-using-a-calculated-default-value/).

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    edit: onEdit
});

function onEdit(editEvent) {
    // Ignore edits of existing rows.
    if(!editEvent.model.isNew()) { return; }

    editEvent.model.set("actionName", {name: "TEST123"});
}
```

Although as I note in that post, setting the default value with `.set()` might not work in this case, and you might need to edit the text in the edit box directly:

```
editEvent.container
         .find("[name=actionName]")
         .val("TEST123")
         .trigger("change");
```

Comment: I also just realized that the element selection that I have was written for the popup editor, so it might be different for inline edit mode.